# Spotify API returns too many albums when browsing an artist

Tags: spotify

After calling sp_artistbrowse_create, and making sure it's completely loaded, I try to retrieve all of the albums by this specified artist, but it seems that those albums are not grouped properly, since I get multiple album objects with the same name. For instance, if I browse David Guetta in the Top Artists list, I get over 600 albums, most of them share the name.
Is this the correct behavior? If it is, is there an attribute I can further group by to get the real listing of that artist's albums?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `sp_album_type()` of the albums - a lot will be singles or "appears on" albums. Also check `sp_album_is_available()` to see if an album is actually available.

Comment: I already filter by availability, and after filtering for type to only be Album, I reduced the set from around 600 to around 400, still with a ton of duplicates. I think it's just a shortcoming of Spotify's music repository. Oh well, thanks for the try!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `/artists/:id/albums` endpoint by default it returns all album types (album, single, appears_on, compilation). [Check Spotify API docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-an-artists-albums) You can add a query to filter out album groups by type(s) that you need to get. Here is an example.

`/artists/:id/albums?include_groups=album,single`

If even this doesn't help you then you can manually filter out album groups.

For example, if you need to get only album groups with album type you can do this. In my example I used JS.

```
const filteredAlbums = albums.filter(
    (album) => (album.album_group === "album"),
  )
```